# Send arbitrary number of arbitrary length buffers in packets of fixed arbitrary size

Tags: c++, socket, udp

Background:

- I am in earlier stages of implementing a standard on top of an existing 'backend'
- This standard requires that I send data in UDP packets of a size specified at runtime
- All packets must be the same specified size except the last, which can be smaller
- The backend interface supplies me with a number of pointers and buffer lengths (right now only 1 or 2, but will likely need more in the future)
- These buffers are not continuous when there is more than one

I take the buffer pointers and lengths mentioned above from the backend, put them in a `vector` of `std::pair` and send them in the constant size packets using the following function:

```
void send_payload(udp_socket* send_sock, send_image_data* params){
  uint8_t pkt_fmt = 0x83;
  int pktsz_minus_header = params->packet_size - PACKET_OVERHEAD;
  header_64b header;
  std::vector<iovec> iovs;
  int total_to_send = 0;
  int total_sent = 0;
  int cur_packet_sz = 0;
  uint payload_sel = 0;
  int send_idx = 0;

  // Get total bytes to send
  for (auto& payload : params->payloads){
    // payload.second is the buffer length parameter
    total_to_send += payload.second;
  }

  // Set up header once
  header.status = params->status;
  header.flag = params->flags;
  header.options = pkt_fmt;
  header.blockID_upper = htonl(params->block_num >> 32);
  header.blockID_lower = htonl(params->block_num);
  header.packetID = htonl(params->packet_num);

  iovec header_iov;
  header_iov.iov_base = &header;
  header_iov.iov_len = sizeof(header_64b);

  while (total_sent < total_to_send){
    // Reset packet iovs
    header.packetID = htonl(params->packet_num);
    iovs.clear();
    iovs.push_back(header_iov);
    cur_packet_sz = 0;

    // Fill packet with payloads
    while (cur_packet_sz < pktsz_minus_header && payload_sel < params->payloads.size()){
      iovec temp_iov;
      // .first is pointer to buffer, .second is length of that buffer
      if ((pktsz_minus_header - cur_packet_sz) <= (params->payloads[payload_sel].second - send_idx)){
        // Space left in the packet is less or equal to remainder of current payload
        temp_iov.iov_base = params->payloads[payload_sel].first + send_idx;
        temp_iov.iov_len = pktsz_minus_header - cur_packet_sz;
        iovs.push_back(temp_iov);
        send_idx += pktsz_minus_header - cur_packet_sz;
        cur_packet_sz += pktsz_minus_header - cur_packet_sz;
      } else{
        // Space left in packet is greater than remainder of current payload
        if ((params->payloads[payload_sel].second - send_idx) > 0){
          temp_iov.iov_base = params->payloads[payload_sel].first + send_idx;
          temp_iov.iov_len = params->payloads[payload_sel].second - send_idx;
          iovs.push_back(temp_iov);
          cur_packet_sz += params->payloads[payload_sel].second - send_idx;
        }
        send_idx = 0;
        payload_sel++;
      }
    }

    // Send packets
    send_sock->sendmsg(iovs.data(), iovs.size(), params->dest_addr, params->dest_port);
    total_sent += cur_packet_sz;
    params->packet_num++;
  }
  if (total_sent != total_to_send){
    LOG_WRN("Sent %d bytes, expected to send %d bytes", total_sent, total_to_send);
  }
}
```

This is my second attempt and I'm fairly certain it should work with any combination of buffers and packet sizes (although I have not tested a significant portion of combinations).

I'm looking for just about any kind of input/review since this is the first time anyone but me will be looking at the code in the year and a half I've been working on it on and off. Mainly readability/maintainability focused.

I'm not very concerned about C++ style or best practices as the whole codebase I am working on top of is C styled C++, but if I could make some changes to better adhere without making it alien to someone whos used to C, I would accept that.

For completeness, here are the custom classes involved:
`struct send_data`:

```
struct send_data{
  uint32_t dest_addr;
  uint32_t dest_port;
  uint64_t block_num;
  uint32_t packet_num;
  uint32_t img_format;
  uint16_t status;
  uint16_t flags;
  uint16_t payload_type;
  uint64_t timestamp;
  uint32_t res_x;
  uint32_t res_y;
  uint16_t packet_size;
  std::vector<std::pair<uint8_t*, int>> payloads;
};
```

`class udp_socket:`

```
class udp_socket{
private:
    int m_socket_fd;

public:
    udp_socket();
    int send(uint8_t* data, size_t len, uint32_t dest_addr, uint16_t dest_port);
    int sendmsg(iovec* iov, int iov_len, uint32_t dest_addr, uint16_t dest_port);
};

udp_socket::udp_socket(){
    int retval;
    m_socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    int sendbuf = 1024 * 1024 * 64;
    socklen_t s;
    s = sizeof(sendbuf);
    retval = setsockopt(m_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sendbuf, s);
    struct sockaddr_in socket_bind;

    socket_bind.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_bind.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0xA9FE6464);
    socket_bind.sin_port = htons(0xC002);

    bind(m_socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&socket_bind, sizeof(socket_bind));
}

// Send single packet using sendto() and returns the retval from sendto(). Requires address info to be supplied
int udp_socket::send(uint8_t* data, size_t len, uint32_t dest_addr, uint16_t dest_port){
    int retval;
    sockaddr_in dest_sock;
    dest_sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_sock.sin_port = htons(dest_port);
    dest_sock.sin_addr = (in_addr)htonl(dest_addr);

    if ((retval = sendto(m_socket_fd, data, len, MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_ZEROCOPY, (sockaddr*)&dest_sock, sizeof(sockaddr_in))) < 0){
        LOG_ERR("Failed to send data on socket: %s", strerror(errno));
    }

    return retval;
}

// Send iovec of messages using sendmsg(), returns the value returned by sendmsg()
int udp_socket::sendmsg(iovec* iov, int iov_len, uint32_t dest_addr, uint16_t dest_port){
    int retval;
    sockaddr_in dest_sock;
    msghdr message_hdr;

    dest_sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_sock.sin_port = htons(dest_port);
    dest_sock.sin_addr = (in_addr)htonl(dest_addr);
    message_hdr.msg_controllen = 0;
    message_hdr.msg_flags = 0;
    message_hdr.msg_iov = iov;
    message_hdr.msg_iovlen = iov_len;
    message_hdr.msg_name = &dest_sock;
    message_hdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

    if ((retval = sendmsg(m_socket_fd, &message_hdr, 0)) < 0){
        LOG_ERR("Failed to send data on socket: %s", strerror(errno));
    }

    return retval;
}
```

`struct header_64b:`

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
    uint16_t status;
    uint16_t flag;
    uint8_t options;
    uint32_t blockID_upper;
    uint32_t blockID_lower;
    uint32_t packetID;
} header_64b;
```

Comment: Are you including `<stdint.h>` instead of `<cstdint>`?  Prefer the C++ header, which puts the identifiers into the `std` namespace.  (In general, it's better to provide _complete_ code for review - even more so if it's testable by reviewers)

Comment: I spent an hour reviewing your previous question (on the same lines) yesterday which you deleted. This was after we had interacted in the comments where I had told you that I had already spent 20 mins on it. Don't do that, it wastes other people's time.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat sorry about that. I was concerned as a high reputation user mentioned that the question was at risk of being closed, and mentioned I should vote to close. My intention was to prevent anyone else from spending time on a potentially bad question that may not be there by the time they get back anyway, very sorry that was the case for you.

Answer (score 6):

## contract

There's no Doxygen or other comments, so the signature
is being asked to do some heavy lifting for the documentation:

```
void send_payload(udp_socket* send_sock, send_image_data* params) {
```

As a maintenance engineer a few months down the road,
I would *really* want to see some of the "review context"
disclosed in the OP, plus some which was not disclosed
like a citation of the proprietary protocol spec
this function claims to conform to.

In other words, be explicit about what
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
this function promises to implement.

---

## size_t

```
  uint payload_sel = 0;
```

It looks like this wants to be of type `size_t` rather than unsigned integer.
(Dunno what "selection" or "selector" or "selected" means in this context.)

On this topic, it seems adventurous to tell the compiler
that `pktsz_minus_header` can take on negative values.

And a bunch of other zero initializations of `int`s here
look like they should probably be of `size_t`'s.

---

## extract helper

```
  // Get total bytes to send
  for (auto& payload : params->payloads){
    // payload.second is the buffer length parameter
```

Thank you for that initial comment, it is helpful.
But as usual, when Author feels the need to write such
a comment, it usually indicates the code is asking
for a tiny trivial helper to be extracted, one
we could name `get_total_bytes_to_send`.
The name helps maintenance engineers,
and breaking it out would allow a test suite
to unit test it separately from the rest of the code.

Thank you for the second comment, it is even more helpful.
Given the need of writing it,
perhaps we'd like to reconsider the `std::pair` decision?
It might be worth declaring a struct that offers meaningful identifiers.
Even if it's just a type pun for a pair.

Similar remarks for the `temp_iov` elements.

```
  // Set up header once
```

This is another nice "structuring" comment.
And again it suggests that it might be useful to break out
a tiny trivial helper, in the hopes of shrinking the
body of `send_payload` so one can visually take it in
all at once without vertical scrolling.

---

## loop variant

You have a pair of `while` loops.

It wouldn't hurt to explicitly write down the
condition that each loop strives to always make true.
As a comment.
Or even as an `assert`.

---

## bookkeeping

```
  while (total_sent < total_to_send) {
```

This seems wonderfully clear.

```
    cur_packet_sz = 0;
```

I found that a little confusing.
I mean, didn't we just put `sizeof(header_64b)` bytes
into the packet we're about to send?

We are juggling two different measures: number of app-level bytes
and number of UDP payload bytes we're about to send out over the wire.
(And BTW I love the `pktsz_minus_header` identifier, it is explicit and clear.)
Consider avoiding differences like `params->packet_size - PACKET_OVERHEAD`,
and just doing bookkeeping in terms of UDP payload bytes.

If you reject that approach, then you may want to
improve how identifiers and comments distinguish
between the two measures.
When I look at identifiers like `send_idx` and `cur_packet_sz`,
I feel that they are well named, yet there's no consistent
prefix that distinguishes between an app payload measure
and a packet measure.

---

## helper predicate

```
        // Space left in the packet is less or equal to remainder of current payload
```

This is a terrific comment, and I thank you for it.

Consider turning the boolean expression into a
tiny helper named `remainder_of_payload_fits_in_packet`.
Then we won't need the comment, nor its complement comment.

Additionally, the entire `if` / `else` could usefully be
broken out as a helper whose
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
is to queue up one more I/O vector along with some bookkeeping
(or maybe do the bookkeeping up in the caller).

---

## assert

```
  if (total_sent != total_to_send){
    LOG_WRN("Sent %d bytes, expected to send %d bytes", total_sent, total_to_send);
  }
```

I don't understand the "warning" aspect.

I mean, we just proved a theorem, right?
If there's a mismatch between the totals,
we failed to deliver on our contract,
we blew a promise.
So tear the process down with a fatal diagnostic,
to encourage it being fixed sooner than later.

---

## code coverage

Recommend you measure code coverage,
in terms of source lines but also conjuncts
like that `payload_sel < params->payloads.size()` comparison.

An automated test suite that fuzzes the payload lengths wouldn't hurt.
This is a simple enough input space that simply iterating over the
payload lengths of interest should suffice.

---

This codebase appears to achieve its design goals.
It is significantly more readable than yesterday's iteration of the same code.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: By "loop variant" you've meant a "loop invariant", haven't you?

Comment: Great feedback, especially about **Documentation**: I have a TODO (that I should have included... will add) that would explain some things like warning vs error in this context. Doxygen is a stretch (for now) but I can do better than nothing. ***Helpers**: I debated a small `struct` vs a `pair`, got a bit caught up in trying something new with C++. 
 **Bookkeeping**: Looking at it from the perspective you provide, yea, I could be clearer and less confusing. I appreciate some fresh eyes on it. I'll have to make some changes and add and edit with your suggestions in mind

Comment: @vnp, roughly, "yes!". Often we speak of "class invariants", the responsibilities a class takes on once its ctor returns. Within a method or function we can certainly talk about maintaining such invariants. But for a loop, usually we're trying to prove the loop always terminates successfully, such as "number of unsent bytes decrements toward zero", so we tend to talk about a loop variant like "x₁ < x₀, unsent bytes decreased". But hey, if you want to say "assert some_invariant()" inside a loop, sure, I'm with you!

Comment: Hi, J_H, you mention a _'yesterday's iteration of the same code'_ – is it available somewhere at StackExchange sites?

Comment: @CiaPan, no, the Author elected to throw it away on purpose, by choosing the "delete" link. That allowed folks to focus on reviewing just the code of current interest. My remark was intended as a compliment to the process. Given the observed progress and attention to detail, I have reason to believe that subsequent iterations will show additional marked improvement.

Comment: @J_H I see. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 6):

- **More functions please**. Every time you feel compelled to put a comment like

  ```
    // Fill packet with payloads
  ```

  you admit that you fail to express yourself clearly in the code. Consider

  ```
    while (total_sent < total_to_send){
        reset_packet_iovs(....);
        header.packetID = htonl(params->packet_num);
        cur_packet_sz = 0;
        fill_packet_with_payload(....);
        ...
    }
  ```
- **Tuples are good. Are they?** Again, a comment

  ```
    // .first is pointer to buffer, .second is length of that buffer
  ```

  suggests that the

  ```
    struct data {
        something buffer;
        something_else length;
    };
  ```

  may suit your purpose better. BTW, why not `std::vector`?
- **Test for failures where failure may happen**

  Testing for `total_sent != total_to_send` is too late. If `send_sock->sendmsg` fails, you are stuck in an infinite loop, or worse you send the wrong data. What you really need to test is a return value of `send_sock->sendmsg` each time you call it, and react accordingly.
- **`#include <algorithm>`**

  Calculation of `total_to_send` seems like an application of `std::accumulate`.

PS: All that said, congratulations. This is way cleaner than the now deleted version.

Answer (score 3):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Tell the compiler which `sendmsg`

The code for `udp_socket::sendmsg()` currently includes this:

```
if ((retval = sendmsg(m_socket_fd, &message_hdr, 0)) < 0){
    LOG_ERR("Failed to send data on socket: %s", strerror(errno));
}
```

This might compile on your machine but on mine it does not because the compiler tries to match this up to the *class* `sendmsg` method and it fails with this error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘udp_socket::sendmsg(int&, msghdr*, int)’
```

Disambiguate this by explicitly telling the compiler that you mean the one in the from `<sys/socket.h>` by changing using the global scope resolution operator `::` like this `::sendmsg(...)`.

### Check for errors

The constructor for the `udp_socket` calls three library functions, `socket`, `setsockopt`, and `bind` but doesn't check the return value for errors for any of them.  Since the object is useless without the underlying socket, I'd recommend throwing an exception on error.  See [C.42](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-throw) for details on why.

### Prefer human-readable constants

The `udp_socket` construct has these three lines:

```
socket_bind.sin_family = AF_INET;
socket_bind.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0xA9FE6464);
socket_bind.sin_port = htons(0xC002);
```

The family is the only one of those set to an easily human-readable value.  I would change the other two to `static` class constants and make them more human readable.

```
static constexpr auto destaddr = "169.254.100.100";
static constexpr auto mysock = 49154;
```

Then I'd use them like this:

```
socket_bind.sin_addr.s_addr = ::inet_addr(destaddr);
socket_bind.sin_port = ::htons(mysock);
```

### Clean up in a destructor

The `udp_socket()` destructor should close the socket.

### Prefer named objects to anonymous ones

The `std::pair` is not really that great here.  It takes no additional overhead to define a class, but I'd go a little further and make it a class that allows incrementing.

```
struct dataptr {
    uint8_t* data;
    unsigned len;
    dataptr& operator+=(std::size_t inc) {
        data += inc;
        len -= inc;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then the last item in the `send_image_data` struct is this:

```
std::vector<dataptr> payloads;
```

### Check for `nullptr`

There are a lot of pointers, but no checking to see if they're `nullptr` or not.  In robust code, I would expect to see either a lot of those kinds of checks or a mechanism for eliminating the need for checking, as in the next suggestion.

### Reconsider the use of pointers

In C++, raw pointers are not as commonly used as in C.  One reason is that we have references in C++ which are effectively the same thing *except* a reference must be a valid object, and therefore can't be `nullptr`.

### Use objects effectively

The point to the code is that we want to send out full packets until we don't have enough data for a full packet.  With that in mind, here's one way rewrite your `send_payload` function:

```
void send_payload(udp_socket& send_sock, send_image_data& params){
  Packet packet(send_sock, params);

  for (const auto& chunk : params.payloads) {
      packet.send(chunk);
  }
  packet.flush();
}
```

Note that what it *doesn't* do is iterate over the payloads to compute the length, because that's not really necessary.  If we look under the hood, here's what that `Packet` class might be:

```
class Packet {
public:
    explicit Packet(udp_socket& send_sock, send_image_data& params)
        : udp{send_sock}
        , params{params}
        , header{
              params.status,
              params.flags,
              0x83,
              htonl(params.block_num >> 32),
              htonl(params.block_num),
              htonl(params.packet_num)
         }
        , remaining{params.packet_size - sizeof(header_64b)}
    {
        iovs.emplace_back(&header, sizeof(header));
    }
    void send(dataptr chunk);
    void flush();
private:
    void send();

    udp_socket& udp;
    send_image_data& params;
    header_64b header;
    std::vector<iovec> iovs;
    std::size_t remaining;
};
```

In real production code, I would probably refactor things so that we don't have to pass and store an entire `udp_socket` or the `send_image_data` structure, but this shows how it might work with something very close to your existing interfaces.

It only has two public functions, other than the constructor, which I've inlined.  The `send()` function just adds data from the passed chunk until there's nothing left.  Each time the packet is full, it sends.  If it's a partial packet, it just appends without sending.  Note here that the passed data item is a copy and not a pointer or reference, so we don't have to modify the original.

```
void Packet::send(dataptr chunk) {
    while (chunk.len >= remaining) {
        iovs.emplace_back(chunk.data, remaining);
        chunk += remaining;
        send();
    }
    if (chunk.len) {
        iovs.emplace_back(chunk.data, chunk.len);
        remaining -= chunk.len;
    }
}
```

Here's the private `send` function:

```
void Packet::send() {
    flush();
    header.packetID = htonl(++params.packet_num);
    iovs.erase(iovs.begin() + 1, iovs.end()); 
    remaining = params.packet_size - sizeof(header_64b);
}
```

Finally, the `flush` function:

```
void Packet::flush() {
    udp.sendmsg(iovs.data(), iovs.size(), params.dest_addr, params.dest_port);
}
```

### Using C++ in a C-based project

If you use C++ as only a slightly better C, you're ignoring a lot of benefits.  Even if you have to interface with standard C functions or callers, there are plenty of ways to use C++ more effectively, as I hope this example shows.

Comment: Yes! Excellent review. I especially appreciate the `dataptr& operator+=` remark, one which I had a nebulous feeling about but wasn't quite sure how to express it in a precise way. And the `send_payload` / `Packet::send(dataptr chunk)` code is exactly what I _wish_ I had been reading.